# Comment le mot latin « musculus » (petite souris) peut être à l'origine du mot français « muscle » ?

Tags: étymologie, origine-ou-raison

En faisant des recherches sur l'étymologie du mot « muscle », je suis tombé sur le mot latin **musculus**, un diminutif de *mus* (souris) pour désigner une *petite souris*.

J'ai beau eu chercher un peu partout (**[TLFi sur le CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/muscle)** qui ne semble que valider l'origine de l'étymologie ne manière nébuleuse *à mes yeux de profane*, *Antidote* et divers autres dictionnaires ou wiki…), rien n'y fait : l'étymologie du mot est systématiquement présentée sans explication, comme s'il était logique qu'un mot désignant une petite souris puisse en venir à désigner un muscle.

C'est d'ailleurs la même chose en anglais, et je n'ai pas trouvé plus d'explication, ni dans l'[*American Heritage*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=muscle) ni dans aucune autre source…

Comment: Good question! For a curiously coincidental, yet TOTALLY irrelevant "combination" of "mus[k]" and "rat" see [muskrat.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=muskrat)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Musculus* était déjà utilisé en latin pour designer le muscle.

Il a pris ce sens en étendant son usage (à la base utilisé seulement pour un muscle de la jambe — c.f. les pièces de viande que l'on vend encore sous le nom de souris, souvent pour l'Agneau) à la totalité des muscles.

À la base, ce muscle (situé au niveau du tibia) a été nommé ainsi en raison de sa forme ovale s'apparentant à une souris.

Comment: +1 pour cette réponse intéressante, merci beaucoup, serait-il possible d'avoir une ou plusieurs sources SVP ?

Comment: Gaffiot, et connaissance personnelles. Ça releve plus de choses que j'ai entendu lors de cours et je n'ai pas de sources formelles, mais j'imagine que ça doit pouvoir se trouver.

Comment: @PascalQyy: *musculus* en latin signifie « petite souris » (diminutif du *mus* : « souris ») et « muscle », c'est un emprunt au grec *μυς* qui désignait déjà « souris » et « muscle » en grec. Source : *Le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey) qui parle d'une « image ». D'ailleurs souris en anglais se dit *mouse* et *Maus* en allemand. [à suivre]

Comment: [suite] L'OED signale que le mot anglais *muscle* est un emprunt à l'ancien français « muscle » 
[ L. *musculus*, dim. of *mus* mouse, the form of certain muscles having some resemblance to that of a mouse. ...
The word is found in all the Rom. langs.: Pr. *muscle*, *moscle*, Sp. *músculo* (also in the popular form *muslo* thigh), Pg. musculo, It. muscolo; also in the mod. Teut. langs., Ger., Du., Da., Sw. *muskel*.]

Answer (score 4):

***Musculus*** avait déjà en Latin deux autres acceptions liées à l'aspect d'une souris, une forme arrondie et allongée avec une extrémité pointue : **muscle** déjà cité mais aussi **moule** (le mollusque) qui partagent tout deux la même étymologie.

[Abrégé du dictionnaire universel Français et Latin 1762](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Kk3bjOmImRQC&pg=PA925&lpg=PA925#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]

[Dictionnaire Gaffiot 1934](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=musculus):

[image]

Comment: merci pour cette réponse, aurriez vous quelques sources s’il vous plais ?

Comment: Deux extraits de dictionnaires ajoutés à ma réponse.

Answer (score 3):

Voici la définition complète du Littré :

> MUSCLE [mu-skl'] s. m.  Terme d'anatomie. Organe charnu, composé de
>   fibres irritables, dont les contractions déterminées soit par la
>   volonté soit par certaines irritations, produisent tous les mouvements
>   des animaux. Le muscle se contracte sous l'influence de la volonté, et
>   cette volonté lui est transmise du cerveau par le nerf. La tête, la
>   queue, le ventre d'un muscle. Ce sculpteur rend bien les muscles. 
>   ♦ La langue est un tissu de petits muscles, FÉN., Exist. 40

**HISTORIQUE**

> XIVe s. ♦ La corde [tendon], les muscles, la main, H. DE MONDEVILLE,
>   f° 8  XVIe s. ♦ Muscle est l'instrument du mouvement volontaire, PARÉ,
>   I, 8 ♦ Quelle est l'insertion et la teste du muscle, telle est la
>   situation de son ventre et de sa queue, PARÉ, XIII, 18

**ÉTYMOLOGIE**

> Provenç. muscle, moscle ; esp. musculo ; ital. muscolo ; du lat.
>   musculus, muscle et aussi petit rat ; grec, mot traduit par muscle et
>   aussi rat ; sanscr. mûsha, rat, du radical mûsch, dérober. On peut
>   rapprocher de musculus, petite souris, ceci, que dans le gigot de
>   mouton le muscle de la jambe se nomme souris.

Answer (score 1):

Le scientifique qui a nommé les muscles trouvait que leurs mouvements ressemblaient à des souris au travail (Marieb, p. 176)

Answer (score 0):

Vient bien du grec. Les athlètes contractaient leur biceps, le muscle gonflait et remontait le long du bras, donnant l'image d'une souris se faufilant sous un tapis, D'où le " musculus ".